# Defining qubit operator from scratch

Tags: programming, qiskit, chemistry

I'm a beginner with Qiskit and the Python language at all.

Here is my question:
One of the VQE function arguments is qubit operator (`qubitOp`).
I saw some examples where the `qubitOp` object was produced by some already existing `Qiskit` module.

For example, in the following fragment:

```
qubitOp, offset = max_cut.get_max_cut_qubitops(w)
```

`qubitOp` is an Ising Hamiltonian produced from the connection weights matrix.

But how can I define the `qubitOp` entirely by myself, from the very beginning?
(My actual goal is to enrich the Ising Hamiltonian with spin's interactions with the external magnetic field).
Thanks!

Comment: can you include a minimal working example? (here that would be including the imports needed to have that line of code working). A link to the example page you are referring to would also be nice

Comment: you can get an idea of how you can define a `qubitOp` by yourself by having a look at the source code for `get_max_cut_qubitops`, which you can find [here](https://github.com/Qiskit/qiskit-aqua/blob/16dbb034cc0871c4ccf4ac0fe04b5878a54aa487/qiskit/aqua/translators/ising/max_cut.py#L71-L94). But a minimal working example would help me get a quick example working more quickly

Answer (score 5):

The question refers to the VQE, so let's start with this and Max_Cut; they can be built on the VQE. There used to be a vqe.ipynp but I can't find, look for [an example](https://github.com/Qiskit/qiskit-tutorials/blob/master/community/aqua/vqe2iqpe.ipynb).

The VQE algorithm doesn't need much input. You can fill it with the `paulis_dict`. This could be a simple Z gate for finding the eigenvalues= -1.

```
pauli_dict = {
    'paulis': [{"coeff": {"imag": 0.0, "real": 1}, "label": "Z"}]
}

qubitOp = Operator.load_from_dict(pauli_dict)
print(qubitOp)
```

I will publish my VQE test on github soon. I want to compare Rigetti and IBM VQE.